# how can I connect multiple clients to same websocket using signalr?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, websocket, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I have a web MVC 5 application, I tested it locally and worked fine.

Is it possible to keep track of connected users on a local variable? should I store it on the database?

I have moderator view and player view, every time a player comes online a counter should add one, it works on localhost but won't work when deployed to azure (I enabled web sockets).

Is there a way to check for an open connection and make every client connect to that one?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Connection management is done inside SignalR [and a backplane if you're leveraging one].. I think you're blaming the fact that it works on localhost and not when it's deployed on assigning clients to use a specific socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could override **OnConnected**, **OnReconnected** and **OnDisconnected** methods to trace/count online users in SignalR application, and if you deploy your SignalR application to a Azure website with multiple instances, I advise you [use either a database or Azure table storage for storing connection information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#permanent-external-storage).

Code snippet in Hub class

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    //update the number of online user from database or Azure table storage

    //call function usercounter to update clients to show online user number
    Clients.All.usercounter(userCount);

    return base.OnConnected();
}


public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    //update the number of online user from database or Azure table storage

    Clients.All.usercounter(userCount);

    return base.OnReconnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    //update the number of online user from database or Azure table storage

    Clients.All.usercounter(userCount);

    return base.OnReconnected();
}
```

Besides, [SignalR Tracing feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing) enables us to view diagnostic information about events in SignalR application, which could help us troubleshoot SignalR issues.

Comment: I thought Redis was the suggested "storage" utility for SignalR backplane? Why would OP use Azure table storage? It's slow enough as it is.

Comment: I mean that we could use these storage services to store connection info, not must use database or azure table storage. Of course, Redis is also a choice.

Comment: Got it - was just curious